# how to insert dynamic array values in database in php?

Tags: php

i need to insert dynamic array value in the database.as i call the array on the `row_count` as the user enter values increases the number of dynamic arrays increases.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {

    echo "<td>" . "Total  Consumption in kw/h" . "</td>";

    $hj[] = $uy11[$i] + $uy112[$i] + $uy111[$i];
    echo "<td>" . round(($hj[$i]), 2) . "</td>";

    if ($tube11 == $tube11 && $fan1 == $fan1 && $bulb1 == $bulb1) {

        $all[] = $tube11[$i] + $fan1[$i] + $bulb1[$i];
        echo "<td>" . round(($all[$i]), 2) . "</td>";

        $bu[] = $hj[$i] - $all[$i];
        echo "<td>" . round(($bu[$i]), 2) . "</td>";

        $bu1[] = ($bu[$i] / $hj[$i]) * 100;
        echo "<td>" . round(($bu1[$i]), 2) . "</td>";

    } else if ($tube12 == $tube12 && $fan12 == $fan12 && $bulb12 == $bulb12) {

        $aq[] = $tube12[$i] + $fan12[$i] + $bulb12[$i];
        echo "<td>" . $aq . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

$asp  = implode($hj, ',');
$asp1 = explode(',', $asp);
print_r($asp);

$asp2  = implode($all, ',');
$asp22 = explode(',', $asp2);
print_r($asp2);

$sql  = "INSERT INTO dea (did,c1, c2,    timestamp) VALUES ('',$asp, $asp2,'" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "')";
$stmt = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

i above code is executing for one time array but if number the number of array values increases they are not inserted in the database.like if in `$asp` values is `2` and `$asp1` value is `3` they are inserted in db but if the value of `$asp` is `[0]=1, [1]=2` this is not inserted .
i need to insert both these values.

Comment: A word of advice: I don't know your problem domain, so perhaps what you're doing is appropriate, however variable names like `$bu` and `$asp22` and `$uy112` are going to leave you drooling in a corner; best to use more descriptive names.

Comment: sir i just when in array $asp two values or more than two values come how can i insert theses values in the database

Comment: `if ($tube11==$tube11 && $fan1==$fan1 && $bulb1==$bulb1)` This if statement doesn't make sense,  they are always going to be equal.  And the elsif will never be executed. but if you want a new record in the DB, you probably want to move the insert into the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $asp is an array like this:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
```

You can get the values by doing

```
foreach($asp as $key => $value){
   echo $value;
}
```

Since you are a lazy programmer, this is wat you can do:
You want to insert $asp and $asp2 into your database if I get the question right.

```
$new_array = array_combine($asp,$asp2);

foreach($new_array as $key => $value){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO dea (did,c1, c2,    timestamp) VALUES ('',$key, $value,'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
   $stmt = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

And by the way, like Doon said: Your if statements doesn't make any sense.

```
if ($tube11==$tube11 && $fan1==$fan1 && $bulb1==$bulb1)
```

This will always be true.

Comment: how can i insert the value in the database

Comment: By adding the query into the foreach loop

Comment: can u plz edit the code for me

Comment: I edited the code, but this is not the way it usually goes on SO. You need to show some effort too since I already think you didn't even code the code yourself.

Comment: it display :Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\kl2.php on line 617

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\kl2.php on line 619

Comment: Then $asp is not an array like you said.

Comment: Take a look at PHP.NET, read about arrays, serialize() in particular. I don't want to help people in my free time who don't show any effort. You can always HIRE me.

Comment: I love how the answer magically “works” as soon as the notion of money  comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some way to encode the array in your tables.

Either:

1. Use a 'base' table with a separate table for values and link to the array list
2. Encode the whole array and serialize it as a blob
3. Encode the array as base64 (or similar) and write it as characters

Comment: @ashy1234 Stack Overflow is *not* a website where you can get professional programmers write code for you for free.